# What's the error "noDebug mode: unable to process 'evaluate' request" means when I use visual studio code to run Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

An error occured when I run the code and input something.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EflV6.png)
It says "noDebug mode: unable to process 'evaluate' request" .What should I do to solve this problem?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("Welcome to math world.Input 1 to an addiction，2 to a subtraction，3 to a multiplication，4 to a division")
        choice := 0
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &choice)
        var a, b int
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)
        switch choice {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println(add(a, b))
        case 2:
            fmt.Println(subtract(a, b))
        case 3:
            fmt.Println(multiply(a, b))
        case 4:
            fmt.Println(divide(a, b))
        default:
            fmt.Println("The order is not exist!")
        }
    }
}

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func subtract(a, b int) int {
    return a - b
}

func multiply(a, b int) int {
    return a * b
}
func divide(a, b int) int {
    return a / b
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2015) Github issue raised. This may be related to VS Code too as stated.